# How can we split a proton?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, protons, confinement, proton-decay

I have heard the following statements:

1. Quarks always exist in a group of 2 or 3, and can not stand alone.
2. Protons are made up of 2 up quarks, and 1 down quark.
3. Quantum mechanics allows us to entangle a particle by somehow dividing it into 2 (For example, if a proton's energy is 5 joules, if we split into 2 then sum of both splitted particles will have energy sum of 5 joules.)
   Aren't the statements contradicting each other? Please tell me correct if anyone of my statement is incorrect.

Comment: "Quantum mechanics allows us to entangle a particle by somehow dividing it into 2" is incorrect. Where did you hear this? It's likely that you misunderstood what was actually said.

Answer (score 2):

Quarks have a rather ingenious mechanism for making sure they never end up alone. If you try to pull two quarks apart, the [strong force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) will resist, resisting harder and harder the more you pull. Provided you can continue to add energy to pull them apart, eventually you will exceed the mass-energy of the quark pair, and two new quarks will appear, each bound to one of your original, now separated quarks. In other words, you have to add so much energy to separate the pair, that you end up providing enough energy to create new partners for each of the two quarks, and now you have two pairs of quarks instead of one. Something similar happens with groups of three quarks, like a proton.

To summarize, you can certainly split a proton. These types of interactions are exactly why particle accelerators exist. But you will never observe a lone quark.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Quarks always exist in a group of 2 or 3, and can not stand alone.

The twos are pairs of quark- antiquark, so the statement is not correct

> 2. Protons are made up of 2 up quarks, and 1 down quark.

```
 Correct.
```

> 3. Quantum mechanics allows us to entangle a particle by somehow dividing it into 2 (For example, if a proton's energy is 5 joules, if we split into 2 then sum of both splitted particles will have energy sum of 5 joules.)

> Aren't the statements contradicting each other?

No, they are partial statements describing the [standard model of particle physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). There are a large number of axiomatic statements and quantum number conservation laws that are involved in the standard model, which describes particle interactions at present.

Now to answer the title:

> How can we split the proton

Is: by involving it in very high energy interactions.

The [quark-gluon plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma), studied at LHC at Cern, results from  split protons and neutrons.

Answer (score 0):

1. Quarks at our universe's (and the environment we are used to) current energy levels exist in confinement. This is caused by something called asymptotic freedom.

> Asymptotic freedom is a feature of quantum chromodynamics (QCD), the quantum field theory of the strong interaction between quarks and gluons, the fundamental constituents of nuclear matter. Quarks interact weakly at high energies, allowing perturbative calculations. At low energies the interaction becomes strong, leading to the confinement of quarks and gluons within composite hadrons.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_freedom

2. Protons are made up of a sea of quarks, the two up and one down quark are just what we call valence quarks

> This is a lie — a white lie, but a big one.  In fact there are zillions of gluons, antiquarks, and quarks in a proton.   The standard shorthand, “the proton is made from two up quarks and one down quark”, is really a statement that the proton has two more up quarks than up antiquarks, and one more down quark than down antiquarks.   To make the glib shorthand correct you need to add the phrase “plus zillions of gluons and zillions of quark-antiquark pairs.”  Without this phrase, one’s view of the proton is so simplistic that it is not possible to understand the LHC at all.

[image]

https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/

3. I believe you are confusing protons with photons. And I believe you are talking about Sponteneus Parametric Down Conversion. Of course certainly you can entangle two protons. But splitting them when entangling is something that sounds very much like SPDC with photons.

> Spontaneous parametric down-conversion (also known as SPDC, parametric fluorescence or parametric scattering) is a nonlinear instant optical process that converts one photon of higher energy (namely, a pump photon), into a pair of photons (namely, a signal photon, and an idler photon) of lower energy, in accordance with the law of conservation of energy and law of conservation of momentum. It is an important process in quantum optics, for the generation of entangled photon pairs, and of single photons.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion

So the answer to your question is yes, you can split a proton, but you do not need entanglement for that and when you do, you are not just splitting a simple particle made up of only 3 quarks, but a much more complex object.